# Remove white space between EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

Please look at the screenshot below.

[image]

I am trying to remove the white space just below the EditText. There isn't any margin or padding being set which in turn confuses me. Here is the layout XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/text_hint_search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >

    
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchText"
    android:background="@color/textGreyColor"
    android:text="List of Items"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could anyone guide me where I am falling over?

EDIT: (NEW SCREENSHOT)

[image]

@Nimish Choudhary See the gaps on left and right!

Comment: ooh the one because of the curved edges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for such behavior is that there are some default padding for each view, you can try

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchText"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="List of Items"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: it did the trick! But still has minute gaps on left and right.

Comment: can you upload a screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit or replace the 9.patch drawable used on the EditText view background. There are padding/margin rules added to the 9.patch drawable. 
Learn how to her: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html